# xPath no consigo concatenar el resultado en una sola linea

Tags: xpath, concat

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de realizar una consulta xPath, mi codigo de ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<librerias>
    <libro>
        <titulo>Libro1</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion1</descripcion>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <titulo>ALibro2</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion2</descripcion>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <titulo>ALibro3</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion3</descripcion>
    </libro>
  <libro>
        <titulo>Libro4</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion4</descripcion>
    </libro>
</librerias>
```

Y esta es la consulta que ejecuto:

```
//titulo[starts-with(.,"A")]/text()|//titulo[starts-with(.,"A")]/..//descripcion/text()
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
ALibro2
Descripcion2
ALibro3
Descripcion3
```

Lo que me gustaría conseguir es lo siguiente:

```
ALibro2 - Descripcion2
ALibro3 - Descripcion3
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer que xpath me devuelva la respuesta en ese formato.

Muchas gracias y ojala alguien pueda echarme una mano.

Comment: ¿Qué version de XPath utilizas? En XPath 2.0 o 3.0 o3.1 podrías seleccionar `//libro[titulo[starts-with(., 'A')]]/concat(titulo, ' - ', descripcion)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado con lo que me has comentado, estaba usando xpath 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Con XPath versión 2.0 o 3.0 o 3.1 podrías seleccionar `//libro[titulo[starts-with(., 'A')]]/concat(titulo, ' - ', descripcion)`:

```js
const xml = `<librerias>
    <libro>
        <titulo>Libro1</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion1</descripcion>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <titulo>ALibro2</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion2</descripcion>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <titulo>ALibro3</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion3</descripcion>
    </libro>
  <libro>
        <titulo>Libro4</titulo>
        <descripcion>Descripcion4</descripcion>
    </libro>
</librerias>`;

const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`parse-xml($xml)//libro[titulo[starts-with(., 'A')]]/concat(titulo, ' - ', descripcion)`, [], { params: { xml : xml } });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```